# Accessing a std::map with pointer type as key

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, dictionary, reference

I'm trying to use a string as key for an std::map because that string can be changed from different parts of the program but I get a problem that I can store data in the map easily but I can't access it because it is asking for the pointer address as the key and I want to access that data from the string's value.

Here is the code

```
using namespace std;

string *AString = "pointer";

map<string *, bool> AMap; //Declare
AMap[AString] = true; //Insert into map with key AString

cerr << AMap["pointer"]; //Does not work
```

Comment: You can't change the key of a entry inside a std::map. I guess you have to rethink why you wan't to do this. You could store a string as key, and everytime the key is changed you erase the old entry and reinsert it to the map with the updated key.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to not use a pointer:

```
using namespace std;

string AString = "pointer";

map<string, bool> AMap;
AMap[AString] = true;

cerr << AMap["pointer"];
```

You really do not want a map key to be changed from other parts of the program while it's in the map. This just asks for trouble and indicates a design problem.

Comment: Why can't we use shared variable as a key in a map?
I want to use a pointer because the value changes and I want the key to stay the same if it changes.

Answer (score 2):

"pointer" is a C string that the AString pointer points to in memory.  You need to do:

```
cerr << AMap[AString];
```

You could also use a a `std::map<std::string,bool>` which is less error prone and what you probably mean to do.  Do you really want to use a pointer for a key?  Creating another pointer pointing to a string with value "pointer"  would not be the same key for instance.

```
std::string *BString(new std::string("pointer")); 
AMap[BString] = true; //Not the same key
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you may be coming from Java or C#?

```
std::string aString = "Not a Pointer";
std::map<std::string, bool> aMap;
aMap[aString] = true;
std::cerr << aMap["pointer"];
```

You should not be using pointers to strings in this case. Just use a map of strings instead of your map of string pointers.

In this case, `std::cerr << aMap["pointer"];` works because the `"pointer"` gets converted into a `std::string` and is then looked up in the map by the string value.